# Haskell: Why can't I pattern match against function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Such as:

```
extract (f x) = x
```

What I want to do is to extract the parameter from a function or a type constructor, such as

```
extract succ 4 = 4
extract Just 4 = 4
```

ps. extract (f x) = f doesn't work either.

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_%28programming_language%29#Functional_Patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the key concepts in functional programming, and especially pure functional programming, is equational reasoning. The `=` in Haskell is actual equality (leaving aside order of pattern matching and such). So when we write

```
f 3 = 12
```

that means `f 3` and `12` are actually the same thing—completely indistinguishable. Since `extract 12` doesn't make any sense, neither does `extract (f 3)`.

To come at it from another direction, at run-time, there is no way to tell that a certain value was formed by applying a certain function to a certain other value. Making such information available would generally be very expensive, and would not often be useful.

Answer (score 4):

The "extracting the argument from a function" would require to invert said function, which is possible only if the function is *injective*. More to the point, assume

```
square x = x*x
```

and

```
root (square x) = x   -- assume it works, somehow
```

We should have

```
root (square 2)    = 2
root (square (-2)) = -2
root 4             = ???
```

The last `4` is both the square of `2` and `-2`, and there's no single result we can associate to it. The `square` function is not injective, so its inverse is not even a function.

Worse, since `4` is equal to both the squares above, referential transparency mandates that the two lines above return the same result. This can not be the case, though.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can pattern match against the structure of your data with a data constructor, like your example, `Just`. What you need is to wrap it in parentheses, `(Just 4)`, otherwise your `extract` function looks like it would be taking a data constructor, and not a constructed value.

In your case, you would want:

```
extract (Just x) = x
```

That's, in fact, part of the `fromJust` function.

The other answer explains why you can't match against function application. To that, I'll add that it would be kind of like a magic way to get an inverse function. If there was an `extract (f x) = x`, it would be like magically having a `g` such that `g . f = id`. In your case, you defined a function `succ` which I presume would be

`succ x = x+1`

Now, if `extract (succ x) = x` was possible, because of equational reasoning, `extract` would of type `Integer -> Integer` and you would magically have constructed the inverse of `succ`, `x-1`.

What is possible though, like I showed above, is matching against the structure of data.

You can define, instead of a function `succ` working on `Integer`s, a new datatype:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

And then easily have an extract function:

```
extra Zero = Zero
extract (Succ x) = x
```

Just remember that you *can*, and are in fact encouraged to, to pattern match against things like `(Just x)`.